# Slow performance Json Images Resolution

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, json, uiimage

My iphone app uses some images as full background. It already downloads the images from a JSon and show them when i run the app. I used this code:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0), ^{
        NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: newIndex[@"imageInside1"]]];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            cell.thumbImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        });
    });
```

But when i run the app, it takes too long to show the images. I think is because the resolution of the images (while it downloads from internet and show it into the app). All of them are 1242x2208.jpg (the same size of the iPhone 6 Plus), because i want to guarantee the correct resolution for all the size background. Am i doing the correct procedure?, is there another way to make it faster?, is it necessary to put them 1242x2208 size?, jpg is the faster type of file for my case?

My app is a tableview with differents items. When the user click on one of the cells, it has to show a three full size background images, inside of a Page ViewController and a Page Control (as the tutorials ViewControllers). I don't know why, but the first image never appears. I have to slide the Page Control to show the second and then, return to the first. In this second opportunity, the first image shows up.

Thanks for your help ¡

Comment: What does this have to do with JSON???

Comment: The images are downloaded from {"imageInside1":"www.example.com/img.jpg"} with the code above. I don´t know if it is the correct way. I don´t know why is too slow...does it have to do with Json?

Comment: Nothing to do with JSON- that is simply the manner in which the information is structured. Where XML would have `<tag>info</tag>`, the same in JSON would be `{"tag":"info"}` (essentially). It has very *very* little to do with how long it takes to download an image.

Answer (score 1):

its because you are assigning the UIImageView asynchronously, all UI changes must occur synchronously on the main thread for them to perform properly, change your second async method to just plain sync and it should work

```
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        cell.thumbImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    });
```

but other than having a faster internet connection, you cant really speed up the download of the image

Comment: Thanks @Fonix for your answer. I tried your recommendation, sadly, it doesn't work. It´s still slow. Do you have another idea to make it faster?

Comment: either make the images smaller so they download faster, or get a faster internet connection heh, not much you can do im afraid. if you know what the images are going to be beforehand, maybe start downloading them before you actually need them?